# Is multidimensional faceting possible in Solr?

Tags: solr

It's working great for a single field but what I need is to combine multiple fields. For example; Students. Each student has age and grade data. I want to show the result like this:

age: **20**
**100-90** (70 students)
**90-80** (120 students)
**80-70** (40 students)

age: **21**
**100-90** (60 students)
**90-80** (110 students)
**80-70** (20 students)

age: **22**
**100-90** (70 students)
**90-80** (120 students)
**80-70** (40 students)

Only thing that come up to my mind is fetching age and grades as facets and searching each facet again. Like, search age 20 for grade 100-90, 90-80, 80-70.. and do the same thing for other ages. Is there an easier way to do that in Solr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Solr Pivot faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting) and watch [The Many Facets of Apache Solr by Yonik Seeley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyjiLYN-qIk). Pivot faceting is might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The link to the video is broken.

Answer (score 4):

facet.pivot available in Solr4